# The equation $f(s)=a$ has a finite number of solution

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function. I am asking about this problem:

What are sufficient conditions (and possibly necessary conditions) in which the equation $$f(s)=a$$ has a finite number of solution with respect to $s$. Here $a≠0$.

Comment: $a \neq 0$ is irrelevant, no?

Comment: This is a main condition.

Comment: But if $a\neq 0$, then can't we set $g(s)=f(s)-a$, which is still analytic, and thus obtain the exact same problem without the restriction $a \neq 0$?

Comment: @DevlinMallory: Yes, you are right.

Comment: is that for all $a,$ $f$ should have finite number of solutions?

Comment: @leshik: No, for a particular value of $a$.

Comment: if $f$ takes value $a$ finitely many times then $f=Pe^g+a$ for some polynomial $P$ and entire function $g.$ Of course, I assume that $f$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the domain of your function. Since you have not specified it, I will assume that your function is defined over the complex plane $\mathbb C$ and for  $a\in\mathbb{C},$ $f(z)=a$ has finite number of solutions. Let $P$ be a polynomial, that has all roots (counting multiplicities) as $f(z)-a$ and only them.
Then, $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{P(z)}$ is an entire function that does not vanish. Therefore, $h(z)=e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g.$ Thus,  $f(z)=P(z)e^{g(z)}+a.$