# What happen if there is several $a$ such that equation have finite number of solutions?

Tags: real-analysis

The motivation to this question can be found in

[The equation $f(s)=a$ has a finite number of solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418491/the-equation-fs-a-has-a-finite-number-of-solution)

My question is:

What happen (regarding the equation $f(z)=P(z)e^{g(z)}+a$) if there is several $a$ such that equation have finite number of solutions?

(a) finite number of $a$'s,

(b) infinite number of $a$'s. Does there is a contradiction?

Comment: @leshik: Can you explain to me more about the unicity of a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is not a polynomial, then $z=\infty$ is an essential singularity for $f.$  Big Picard theorem implies that $f$ takes each value infinitely often with at most one exception.

Comment: In both cases (a) and (b)? No?

Comment: this is a general result.

Comment: So $a$ must be unique in the earlier question?

Comment: Yes. It is either unique or, in case $f$ is a polynomial, all $\mathbb{C}.$